# BBox not properly established when including a pdf figure in LaTeX

Tags: matplotlib, latex, bounding-box

I am trying to include a pdf figure in latex. I created the figure in python using matplotlib in a simple way

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(random(100))
plt.savefig('figure.pdf',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

However, when compilin the latex document I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in figures/figure.pdf (no B
oundingBox).
```

The problem is how matplotlib establishes the bounding box, but I just can't find a way to solve this. Could anyone give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your TeX code and are you running plain latex or pdflatex? Also, you'll be served better at tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not the matplotlib bbox, but the way the latex compilation was made. In this case, pdflatex is required to compile the document, not latex.